# How to Create the Upload File for Application Loader?

Tags: ios, upload, release, ipa, application-loader

When I use Application Loader, I get to the point where it asks me to "Choose..." the file to be uploaded.

If I understand correctly, it supposes to be the appName.app file I see under "Products" on my app bundle (I right click it and select "Show in Finder" to get to the specific file in library; then I'm supposed to ZIP it and the ZIP file is what I will choose in Application Loader). First, am I correct with this assumption?

if yes...

What should I define different in XCode than the way I used to build the application for testing (on simulator and on my personal iPhone)?

Should I change the **Info--->Command-line build use** from **Debug** to **Release**?

How should I define the **Build Settings--->Code Signing** section (in which field should I select the "**iPhone Developer**" option and in which should it be "**iPhone Distribution**")?

Are there any other important Info/Build Settings/p.list/etc... fields I should relate to?

any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 94, accepted):

- Launch Xcode 5 (<kbd>Product</kbd> > <kbd>Archive</kbd> to build the archive)
- Goto <kbd>Window</kbd> > <kbd>Organizer</kbd>
- Select the latest archive and click on the <kbd>Export</kbd> button
- Select <kbd>Save for Enterprise Deployment</kbd> or <kbd>Save for Ad Hoc Deployment</kbd>
- Select your provisioning profile and then <kbd>Export</kbd>
- Choose a location to save the .ipa file

This is basically it. Hope it will help anyone looking for the answer.

Comment: Still is strange to me that it is not visible at first that this option is also good to create AppStore .ipa packages for your project (selecting the AppStore Provisioning Profile ofcourse). I Like to have the package for reference in my scm but the application loader isn't quite useful in this scenario; delivery via XCode is just as good I presume.. Apple states the following for "Using Application Loader"
Application Loader is a tool to help you upload your apps to iTunes Connect. It’s particularly helpful if your app includes In-App Purchase products that need to be configured for the app."

Comment: Does this mean that the Application Loader (re?) signs the application? I thought that an Ad Hoc distribution profile was used for the (limited) number of specified UDIDs. In the non-Application Loader way of uploading a binary, when you select Distribution for App Store, you select the App Store specific provisioning profile?        (I'm asking because I uploaded my binary today with the Application Loader and selected the last archive that I'd saved for Ad Hoc distro...  then questioned whether that was right, after the fact. It's Waiting for Review though, so I guess it's ok?)   Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go and login to the [iOS Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action). From the menu on the left, select "Distribution" and you should be landed to the "Prepare App" tab. Read through the instructions carefully, you mostly need the information under "Building your Application with Xcode for Distribution".
Remember that "Only Team Agents are authorized to prepare and submit applications for distribution".

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the file that you need to choose is a "*.ipa" file which I was able to generated by archiving to project.

If you have xcode 4 it is recommended to add another scheme e.g. dist scheme and configure the scheme to release.
Than compile (using the dist scheme) and go to the organizer to view/share/ or submit the application.

If you are using xcode 4, it has a bug which crashes the xcode if you choose validate or submit, in this case you should save upload the *.ipa using the application loader.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you create an .ipa file with Xcode 4.3 then?  Mine always generates .xcarchive files instead!

Comment: hm... does Apple intentionally make this so tough so that only the smart people can submit it and therefore the app is by smart people only

Comment: I think it's more to filter out the non-submissive types.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue simply by renaming the storyboard file for the iPhone storyboard to Main_iPhone.storyboard.

Xcode looks for this file because it's built in to your plist (property list) file when you create a new project.

I created a universal app, and somewhere along the way I renamed that storyboard file.  Because my app is universal, I didn't want to go monkeying around with deleting plist keys.

After trying again, I got the same error.  Then I quit Xcode, restarted, re-validated, and it worked.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest Application loader from here: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg.
(Download the latest one. This doesn't get updated automatically. If you haven;t downloaded this recetnly you probably have a older version that may have errors which are solved in the newer version)

Then 1) Archive your build.
2) After your build archives, you will be in the builds page.
3) Export that build
4) Click "App Store blablabla" row
5) Save the file somewhere
6) Open Application Loader
7) click upload
8) upload that saved file.

Done.