# Is there a way to send .ipa generated on a computer, from another to the AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, submit, xcode6, ipa

I was wondering if it's possible (**already googled it**) to generate an .ipa of an application on a `computer A`, send the .ipa to a `computer B`, and the send the .ipa from `computer B` to the AppStore ?

Can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried [Application Loader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf) ? See page 35 'Delivering Your App Binary'

Comment: Expanding on @Pierre-Loup 's answer, you can using Build > Archive to generate an archive, then from the Window > Organizer, you select that archive, hit "Export" and select for "iOS Appstore Distribution", this will generate the IPA file. You can then send it to computer B to use Application Loader to upload to iOS App Store, so as long as you use the correct Apple account to login to Application Loader.

Comment: Gonna check for Application Loader. Come back to you two

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937660/how-to-create-the-upload-file-for-application-loader) might answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the application loader to do that.

I downloaded it on the iTunesConnect portal then I exported my app as an archive. 
I then sent it to my mate and he uploaded it with the app.